# Find Recyclerview using Espresso

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

Is there a way to find view of kind in Espresso? I want to find a RecyclerView in the view hierarchy and carry out scroll action. The id and tag are not fixed i.e not possible to use withId or withTag etc.

Thanks!

Comment: why adding `android:id` or `android:contentDescription` is for you not possible?

Comment: I found the answer for this. Used TypeSafeMatcher. Created a class extending the same. In matchesSafely checked if item instanceof RecyclerView

Comment: Make an edit of your post or put it as answer

Answer (score 0):

If it is the only recyclerview on the page, then [isAssignableFrom(RecyclerView.class)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20android.view.View%3E)) will work for you just fine.